The text goes under the OK button in unity textmeshpro
I use unity Unity 2021.3.40f1 and textmeshpro 3.0.9
The text goes under the OK button when typing and OK button block textthis is problem
I didn't find any property to fix this issue. only update to latest version of textmeshpro but problem is still remains.
thanks.

what do you expect the text to do?  if its not part of the button, it seems a poor choice to put it in the same place as the button at all
